# Unable to switch to New window opened in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application, I could see four different windows opened, but when I use getWindowHandles() I could get only three windows references.

Upon clicking a button a new window opens. When I inspect button following code is observed which opens a new window upon clicking.

```
  <input title="Change Credit File (Move Document)" style="width: 140px;" onclick="setAssociationsCreditFile1('3577989','emsprod3572943','abc/123/2385','Record','1','veepuris','abc','http://FTC-abc401.ad.abc.net/','N');" type="button" value="Change Association"/>
```

I used following code to switch to new window opened.

```
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
}
```

Please let me know how to switch to new window that is opened.

Comment: At a time you can switch to only one window.

Comment: @SarithaG I'm trying to switch to only one window.

Comment: If you have only one window then that can work properly. Otherwise it won't work. What is the size of driver.getWindowHandles()?? And which window you want to switch to??

Comment: @SarithaG Its size is 3.But I could see 4 windows opened on my screen.

Comment: are you able to switch to those 4 new windows??

Comment: @SarithaG   I'm able to switch to 3 windows only.getWindowHandle is not able to fetch fourth window name.

Comment: So you want to switch to last window or first window??

Comment: @SarithaG   I'm trying to switch to last window which is opened.I performed activites on prevoius three windows.

Comment: Please refer my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.ToList().Last());
```

Comment: I think I'm implementing in same way but code snippet is different.

Answer (score 0):

They way I'm implementing this is as follows:

```
  Set<String> handles = drv.getWindowHandles();

  <action that opens new window>

  for(String handle : drv.getWindowHandles())
        if(!handles.contains(handle))
            drv.switchTo().window(handle);
```

If you still have only 3 handles, have you maybe started a new driver instance to create a new page somewhere?

Comment: I've placed the code snippet after the button click request.Even I placedThread.sleep(25000) after that request too.However it did not worked.

Comment: No, if it can't find the latest window it wouldn't. Did you ever use a new driver to open a new page? It could explain the smaller windowHandle size. 

EDIT: Make sure that the Set<String> declaration is BEFORE you do the button click, otherwise my chunk of code wouldn't ever change your window

Comment: I've tried your code .Its not giving me the reference to fourth window.Its still pointing to third window .

Comment: And its a fourth window? Is it maybe a pop-up/alert? Thats the only thing that I can think of that might stump it like it has

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to last window by giving the condition.

```
//List of window handles
Set<String> list = driver.getWindowHandles();
int size  = list.size();

for(int i=0; i< size; i++){
    String childWindow = list.get(i);
    if(i==size-1){
       driver.switchTo().window(childWindow);
    }else {
       list.remove(childWindow);
    }
}
```

Comment: It did not give me any lead.The problem is getWindowHandles is returning only 3 values of windows which are already present.Still Stuck up with it..

Comment: Here the condition is given to remove the screen except the last screen...It has to work.